# Logout link in React using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a simple boolean flag to set whether a user is logged in or out to do conditional rendering. I have doubled down with this flag to use it also as a way to logout. I am getting a TypeError that is saying my setIsLoggedIn is not a function, however I am using it in a similar way in another area of my program.

App.js :

```
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/login"
          render={() => (
            <Login
              isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
              setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

A portion of the code for SignedInLinks component:

```
const SignedInLinks = ({ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn }) => {

    const handleLogout = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
    }
    return (
            <li><NavLink to='/login' onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</NavLink> 
            </li>
           )
```

The error is exactly 'TypeError: setIsLoggedIn is not a function'

Comment: Where are you rendering the SignInLinks component

Comment: I have a Navbar component that is doing a conditional: {isLoggedIn ? <SignedInLinks/> : <SignedOutLinks/>}

Comment: No since you aren't passing the props isLoggedIn and setIsLoggedIn to `SignedInLinks` component, you are getting the error

Comment: const SignedInLinks = ({ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn }) I am passing these to my `SignedInLinks`

Comment: with the above code, you aren't passing the props but you are receiving them and unless you pass it you can't receive it. You need to pass the props like `{isLoggedIn ? <SignedInLinks isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}/ > : <SignedOutLinks isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}/>}`

Comment: I saw it as soon as you said I wasnt passing the props to the component properly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Define `handleLogout` in App.js

```
const handleLogout = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
    }


return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/login"
          render={() => (
            <Login
              isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
              handleLogout={handleLogout}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Application of Login/Logout using Hooks**

Hooks.js

```
function Hooks() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClick = e => {
    setLoggedIn(!loggedIn);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {loggedIn ? (
        <SignOut handleClick={handleClick} />
      ) : (
        <SignIn handleClick={handleClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Hooks;
```

SignIn.js

```
function SignIn(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Please signin</h3>
      <button onClick={props.handleClick}>signin</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

SignOut.js

```
function SignOut(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Yay....You are loggedin</h3>
      <button onClick={props.handleClick}>signout</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```